# PHP: Unable to extact particular files from a ZIP archive

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

I am trying to extract files from a zip file, but its failing with following error

`Warning: copy(zip://upload/myzip-file.zip#myzip-file/file_001.csv): Failed to open stream: operation failed in {code line}`

My file `myzip-file.zip` is placed inside `upload` folder, my code is able to read the contents of this file, but its unable to extract file one by one (I want to extract particular files only. I also want to avoid creation of sub folder)

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
    if ($zip->open($zipPath) === true) {
        for($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
            $filename = $zip->getNameIndex($i);
            $fileinfo = pathinfo($filename);
            copy("zip://".$zipPath."#".$filename, "my-path/".$fileinfo['basename']);
        }                  
        $zip->close();                  
    }
```

> I suspect that copy functoin is not able to understand zip://
> I found this sample on net where people have achived same using copy command but its not working for me any more.

Please note

- My php script is at same location as are `upload` and `my-path` (All three in same directory)
- My Zip does contain an extra folder `myzip-file` and its confirmed by extracting the full zip contentents and this sinppet `$zip->getNameIndex($i);` also revealed that.

Please note you don't have to fix it, but if have any sample which is extracting one single file from zip. It will work for me.

Comment: Question: Is it true that both "upload" and "my-path" are two separate sub-directories of current directory holding the PHP file ?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: So your files inside the zip file are contained within a folder name `myzip-file`, is that correct?

Comment: yes, checked with zip tool, also this generated path I got from `$zip->getNameIndex($i);`

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your PHP script, it will work if

- using relative path (so use `$zipPath="./upload/myzip-file.zip";` and `"./my-path/"`)
- my-path is **writable**
- over the iteration, better do not process the "file" if the $filename is actually a directory
- so the directory structure is like the attached picture (myzip-file.zip is placed inside the `upload` folder, the process.php is the PHP to do the job)

So use the following code (I tested in a linux server and it works)

```
<?php

$zipPath="./upload/myzip-file.zip";

$zip = new ZipArchive;
    if ($zip->open($zipPath) === true) {
        for($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
            $filename = $zip->getNameIndex($i);
            $fileinfo = pathinfo($filename);
      
          if (substr($filename, -1) !="/"){
            copy("zip://".$zipPath."#".$filename, "./my-path/".$fileinfo['basename']);
          }
        }                  
        $zip->close();                  
    }

?>
```

[image]